# How int* is bool in C#?

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

I am trying to use pointers in C# like in C.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            int i = 5;
            int* j = &i;
            Console.WriteLine(j);  //cannot convert from 'int*' to 'bool'
        } 

    }
```

I have two queries regarding  this code:

1. How to compile with /unsafe ?
2. Why `Console.Writeline(j)` is trying to convert `j to bool`?

Comment: Best would be to cast the pointer to `IntPtr` (or `int`, `uint`, etc).

Comment: To compile with unsafe get to the project properties =>build and there will be the check mark, "Compile With Unsafe"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Point 2) takes 2 steps:

- `Console.WriteLine()` does not have an overload for `int*`
- Apparently it then tries it's first overload, `WriteLine(bool value)` and cannot find a conversion

I would call this a weak error report.

To print the address, cast it to an `ulong` first.

Answer (score 3):

1. If using csc, add /unsafe; or in a vs project, go to project properties and there is a checkbox
2. Simply it can't find a better match; I'd have to check the spec for the exact order rules, but just treat it as the compiler saying "no suitable match, I'm guessing at this but this doesn't work either"

Answer (score 2):

Writing the value of the pointer is pointless, it is just a random address.  You initialize the pointer with the address of a variable on the stack, such an address doesn't repeat well. You want to dereference the pointer with the * operator.  Like this:

```
        Console.WriteLine(*j);
```

Which writes the pointed-to value, 5 in your case.